# BarChart does not fit on display Iphone

Tags: iphone, swift, ios-charts

This is probably very simple, but I am not used to Iphone programming and Swift yet. I have only worked with Android. I want to use iosChart in my application. I have followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/) tutorial to create a test bar chart.

The problem is that the chart does not fit the screen, but extends outside the display in the emulator. There is probably something easy to fix in the storyboard, but I have not found anything.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

The x-axis should extend to December, but it is not visible.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class DetailedScoreController: UIViewController {
var results : Results

var months: [String]!

// MARK: Initialization
@IBOutlet weak var detailedChart: BarChartView!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.results = Results()!
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("DetailedResultController Created!");
    self.results.printResult()
    self.results.printDetailedResults()

    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Set up barchart

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    detailedChart.data = chartData
}

}
```

Here is how the storyboard looks like, the marked is the bar chart:

[image]

To me it looks like the entire chart should lie in the display.

Comment: Your storyboard is using inferred mode. Have you pinned any constraints?

Comment: I try to but I can't figure out how to make it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your view and select the pin at the bottom right hand corner to add constraints.

Set the top, bottom, left and right to 10 and click 'Add constraints'. It should now show the entire bar chart as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints to your view in storyboard to make it change size to fit the screen:
[About Auto Layout and Layout Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)